# 14-bit left-justified two's complement to a signed short

Tags: c, types, bit-shift, twos-complement

I have two bytes containing a 14-bit left-justified [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) value, and I need to convert it to a signed short value (ranging from -8192 to +8191, I guess?)

What would be the fastest way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply divide by 4.

(Note, right-shift leads to implementation/undefined behaviour.)

Answer (score 1):

A portable solution:

```
short convert(unsigned char hi, unsigned char lo)
{
  int s = (hi << 6) | (lo >> 2);
  if (s >= 8192)
    s -= 16384;
  return s;
}
```

Comment: I do: x = ((int16_t)((byte[0] << 8) | byte[1]) / 4) now, which seems to work fine. Is your solution more portable of faster?

Comment: Which is faster depends on the compiler. Yours exhibits undefined behavior by overflowing a signed integer type, int16_t.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze That won't compile, you've mis-matched the argument names (`lo` vs `low`).

Comment: @unwind Love it when fixing the code means deleting a part of it, even if a single character. :)